# Parse JSON and Filters in Python Django Template

Tags: python, django, django-templates

Foreach in django python

`{{details.variation_values}}`
In django, I'm getting result of **details.variation_values** in JSON Format
But Now i wanna make iterations of JSON result
,For example:
**details.variation_values = ["28","30","32"]**
[Example Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e4hy8.png)
But I need each index in each row

```
{% for data in array %}
<div class="row" id="variationfield{{data}}"> 
 <div class="col-md-9">
  <div class="form-group">
   <input type="text" class="form-control" name="value" placeholder="" value="{{data}}">
  </div>
 </div>
</div>
{% endfor %}
```

Sorry if you're not understanding my problem. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can access `{{ loop.index }}` inside your loop to get the current index of the loop.

```
{% for data in array %}
{{ loop.index }}
<div class="row" id="variationfield{{data}}"> 
 <div class="col-md-9">
  <div class="form-group">
   <input type="text" class="form-control" name="value" placeholder="" value="{{data}}">
  </div>
 </div>
</div>
{% endfor %}
```